# How to adjust VideoView in CardView?

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, android-videoview

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="30dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/black"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/simpleVideoView"  
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

I want to adjust the video in the cardview. Below is the image link.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wbqyc.jpg

Comment: Use this inside VideoView android:scaleType="fitXY" and this app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false" to the cardView

Comment: android:scaleType="fitXY" it will not work in videoview.@Skizo-ozᴉʞS

Answer (score 2):

Your layout_wight and layout_width in card view I think it's to much, maybe you can set for 30dp and cardCornerRadius it's much too, you can set 10dp for better UX.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).